# Correcting correlation coefficient significance (p-value) for dependent samples within Monte Carlo analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I would like to perform hypothesis testing on the significance of the correlation coefficient (Pearson's correlation coefficient) between variable $a$ and variable $b$. I do not have access to such variables directly from the available data $X^{j}$ where $j$ is the index of each experimental session (total number of experimental sessions is N) and we assume these sessions are independent. In order to get enough samples for my hypothesis testing, I draw (with replacement) a subset of samples $X^{j}_{i}$ from the original data of each experimental session $X^{j}$ and then learn a generative model for $X^{j}_{i}$ and calculate variables $a^{j}_{i}$ and $b^{j}_{i}$ in the test set given the learned model.

In a Monte Carlo bootstrap procedure, I repeat this analysis $M$ times for each experimental session and pool all the values for all experimental sessions ($N\times M$ values). Now I want to test whether there exist significant positive correlations between these pooled values of $a^{j}_{i}$ and $b^{j}_{i}$. However, I already introduced correlated/dependent samples due to sampling with the replacement process.

Is there any procedure to correct the p-value I get for the significance of the correlation coefficient between $a$ and $b$? The learning stage is computationally super expensive so I am looking for procedures to do this in an offline manner with already computed values of $a^{j}_{i}$ and $b^{j}_{i}$.